# VS Code Live Server extension goes offline when opening the Chrome dev tools

Tags: google-chrome, visual-studio-code, google-chrome-devtools, liveserver

So I currently have a problem with my browser and my IDE (VSCode).

When I open a local host with the Live Server extension on my project and open the Chrome dev tools, the live server instantly goes offline.

If I don't open it, saving my project does not disable the live server but as soon as it's opened and I come back on my project to make a change and save the files, the live server turns off.

I'm also noticing a change in the dev tools DOM code.

[[That's the notifications I get when it goes offline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ClvE.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/scFiC.png)

I tried to uninstall and install again the extension. I also enabled full reload in my IDE settings I restarted my computer but it didn't fixed the problem.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this with either of the procedures you stated. Check you browser console for related messages and also the network tab. Also check the output logs in VS Code (`View > Ouput`) to see if there are any related messages there. Share what you find by [edit]ing your question post. Also check if the error is due to something about your site's files. Does the issue reproduce if you just use a minimal HTML file?

Comment: I fixed the problem by changing the 'offline' to 'no throttling' next to the responsive dimensions. I guess that it is a rookie mistake.

Comment: If you found a solution, make sure your question post has enough detail to lead logically to that solution ([ask]), then write up an answer ([answer])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so I fixed the problem so here is the solution:

In my Chrome dev tools, on the responsive menu, the option 'Offline' was selected instead of 'No throttling'. It's what causing the problem. I just switched to 'No throttling' and the problem was fixed.